# I can't clear interval

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the interval, which I can not clear after calling the function with a value.

The interval continues to increase the number and returns the percentage of the width.

Here my code:

```
function loadingClient(data) {

    var loadingClientDiv = document.getElementById('loadingClient');
    var percentageLoading = document.getElementsByClassName('percentageLoading');
    var charge = 1;
    var intervalLoadingClient = setInterval(barCharge, 1000);

    function barCharge() {
        if (charge >= 76) {
            clearInterval(intervalLoadingClient);
        } else {
            ++charge;
            $(percentageLoading).css("width", charge + "%");
        }
    }

    if (data === "100") {
        clearInterval(intervalLoadingClient);
        $(percentageLoading).css("width", "100%");
        setTimeout(closeLoadingClient, 5000);
        setTimeout(removeLoadingClient, 7000);

        function closeLoadingClient() {
            $(loadingClientDiv).hide("fade", 1000);
        }

        function removeLoadingClient() {
            $(loadingClientDiv).remove();
        }
    }

}

loadingClient();
```

Comment: `interval` !== `timeout`. You're either clearing or setting the wrong thing.

Comment: @deceze setInterval and setTimeout returns ids from the same pool, and you *can* call any clearXxx on any setXxx, they don't look at the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hudolfhess is correct, you need to be using clearInterval instead of clearTimeout.

Also,

If you are trying to do something like this it wont work.

```js
loadingClient() //Should start the interval.
loadingClient("100") //Should clear the interval, but doesn't.
```

you are trying to do? If so, you need to delcare intervalLoadingClient outside of the scope and avoid re-declaration of the variable when you call the method with parameters.

```js
var intervalLoadingClient;
function loadingClient(data) {

    var loadingClientDiv = document.getElementById('loadingClient');
    var percentageLoading = document.getElementsByClassName('percentageLoading');
    var charge = 1;
    intervalLoadingClient = intervalLoadingClient || setInterval(barCharge, 1000);

    function barCharge() {
        if (charge >= 76) {
            clearInterval(intervalLoadingClient);
        } else {
            ++charge;
            $(percentageLoading).css("width", charge + "%");
        }
    }

    if (data === "100") {
        clearInterval(intervalLoadingClient);
        $(percentageLoading).css("width", "100%");
        setTimeout(closeLoadingClient, 5000);
        setTimeout(removeLoadingClient, 7000);

        function closeLoadingClient() {
            $(loadingClientDiv).hide("fade", 1000);
        }

        function removeLoadingClient() {
            $(loadingClientDiv).remove();
        }
    }

}

loadingClient(); //Starts the interval
loadingClient("100"); //Ends the interval.
```